# Css3 não está funcionando no cordova

Tags: css3, apache-cordova

Estou tentando utilizar *media queries* no meu aplicativo desenvolvido com o Cordova, porem ele não esta funcionando, o código é o seguinte:

```css
#backgroundIndex{
    @media screen and(max-width: 1200px){
        background: red;
    }
    @media screen and(max-width: 740px){
        background: url('../img/background.jpg') repeat top left;
    }
}
```

O que eu gostaria de fazer é: Quando a resolução for menor que 740px o *background* use uma imagem. No caso de ser maior, o *background* seria vermelho.

Quando estou desenvolvendo sites utilizo estes mesmos comandos porém no *mobile* não esta funcionando, mesmo definindo o `viewport`:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Está dando um erro no *inspec*:

> The key "target-densitydpi" is not supported.

Como posso resolver isto?

Comment: Vinicius, minha formatação foi apenas para colocar seu código na formatação correta!

Comment: Parece que esse atributo não é suportado pelo iOS e *deprecated* no Android. Já tentou usar `max-device-width` ao invés de `max-width`?

Comment: Ainda não esta funcionando utilizei `max-device-width`

Answer (score 1):

A sintaxe do `@media-querie` está errada, a classe tem que ficar dentro dele e não fora:

```
@media screen and(max-width: 1200px){
    #backgroundIndex {
        background: red;
    }
}

@media screen and(max-width: 740px){
    #backgroundIndex {
        background: url("../img/background.jpg") repeat top left;
    }
}
```